# PHP exec running in background with Windows & Apache but not Nginx

Tags: php, windows, apache, nginx

I have tried both Apache/PHP and Nginx/PHP with nearly the same configuration.

I am running this script:

```
<?php
exec("calc.exe");
?>
```

In Apache/PHP, calc.exe is not opened but is found running as a background process.
In Nginx/PHP, calc.exe is opened properly.

I would like to use Apache/PHP to open calc.exe properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exec has no functionality with display, it will spawn processes and such under a different user (thus no affect on the current logged in user)

Scenario; your logged in as User1

On php do the following;

```
 Exec("whoami");
```

You will see a different user which apache/web service is running as

Comment: It returns nt authority\system

Comment: Different running users, different display screens essentially

Comment: This helped me solve the issue. I was running Apache from a service, now I am running it from a batch file. Thank you!